# Use REGEXP functions in SQL to insert underscores between capitalized letters and a lowercase letter that precedes it

Tags: sql, presto

What is the correct REGEXP syntax to generate the desired outcome? Thanks!

Table 1 looks like this:

```
user_id      city_state
123          MiamiFlorida
234          PhiladelphiaPennsylvania
345          ClevelandOhio
```

I'd like it to look like this:

---

```
user_id      city_state
123          Miami_Florida
234          Philadelphia_Pennsylvania
345          Cleveland_Ohio
```

====== EDITED ======

After applying @Gary_W's logic via Presto, returned the following result:

```
 USER_ID    FIXED
---------- ------------------------------
       123 Miam1_2lorida
       234 Philadelphi1_2ennsylvania
       345 Clevelan1_2hio
```

How do we retain the final letter?

Comment: How is regex going to parse any random city name from a string?

Comment: Good point. Let me rephrase. Use regexp to: 
1. Find a capitalized letter
2. Determine if there is a letter that precedes the capitalized letter
3. If there is a letter that precedes the capitalized one, insert an underscore between the capitalized letter and the one that precedes it
4. If there isn't a letter that precedes the capitalized letter, do nothing

Comment: @JacobH, I've just clarified the question. Thanks!

Comment: That makes a ton more sense! I'm not that great with regex though, but it's a good question now :)

Comment: what rules in parsing NewYorkNewYork?  Does that become NewYork_NewYork or New_York_New_York?

Comment: It'd be New_York_New_York, strictly speaking.

Comment: Well the matching part is working but you'll need to figure out what Presto uses to refer to the remembered group.  You are getting the group number, not the contents of what the group number is pointing to.

Comment: Use a dollar sign instead of a backslash.  The wonders of Google.https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html

Comment: @Gary_W, amazing! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify an RDBMS, but in Oracle I'd do something like this.  Look for a letter of any case followed by a capital letter and put each in their own group so they are "remembered".  Then replace them with an underscore in between.  Each remembered group is referenced in order by \1, \2 etc.

You should be able to adapt the regex to your flavor.

EDIT - The poster is using Presto, and that tool uses a dollar sign instead of a backslash in front of the remembered group number.

```
SQL> with tbl(user_id,city_state) as (
      select 123, 'MiamiFlorida' from dual union all
      select 234, 'PhiladelphiaPennsylvania' from dual union all
      select 345, 'ClevelandOhio' from dual
    )
    select user_id,
           regexp_replace(city_state, '([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])', '\1_\2') fixed
    from tbl;

   USER_ID FIXED
---------- ------------------------------
       123 Miami_Florida
       234 Philadelphia_Pennsylvania
       345 Cleveland_Ohio
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gary_W. My results looked like the following:


` USER_ID FIXED
---------- ------------------------------
       123 Miam1_2lorida
       234 Philadelphi1_2ennsylvania
       345 Clevelan1_2hio`


How do we retain the final letter?

Comment: Your character for identifying the remembered group must be different.  Please update your original post with the edit button and show your code as the comments don't allow formatting.  Indicate what tool or database you are using too.